# can´t open a popup if the name has a space on it on react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a card in react with a button on it,and the card has as an id the name of the user that the card represents:

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target={`#${truncate(object.name)}`}>
                                            Manage Permissions
                                       </button>

                                        <div className="modal fade" id={truncate(object.name)} tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
```

My problem is that if the user´s name has a sapce on it (if it is for example "my example") the popup wont open.

I create the function truncate that you can see on the data-target to see if with that the popup appeared but it still doesn´t appear.

Truncate function:

```
  let truncate=(name)=>{
  return name.trim();
}
```

I would like to know how to open my popup if the name has a space on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.trim()` won't remove whitespace from the middle of your text.

Try this:

`name.replace(/ /g,'')`